# React Redux is ignoring dispatches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two redux actions, one action called `register` which works, showing the console.log

However `logIn` action doesn't show the console.log, so im assuming there is an issue with redux calling the dispatch in the `logIn` action.

This is not an issue with the reducer, because an action should be able to call the console.log.

I want to know why redux is not calling the dispatch the actions for logIn action. Even if there is an error, i should be getting an error message in `console.log(err.response)` but even that is not rendering on the console tab.

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { history } from '../components/Navbar';

export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";
export const lOG_FAIL = "lOG_FAIL";

export const REG_SUC = "REG_SUCCESS";
export const REG_FAIL = "REG_FAIL";

export const logIn =  (user) => { 
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post('/api/users/loginUser',{
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password
        }).then( (res) => {
             // localStorage.setItem('JWT', res.data.token);
            // history.push('/dashboard');
            dispatch({type: SET_USER, user});
        }).catch((err)=> {
            dispatch({type:  lOG_FAIL, err});
            console.log(err.response.data); // not even showing err console.
            console.log('no console log that appears here either') // doesn't show console log
        })

    }
}


export const register = (user) => { 
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post('/api/users/new',{
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password,
            email: user.email 
        }).then( (res) => {
            // console.log('success')
            history.push('/signIn');
            dispatch({type: REG_SUC, user});
        }).catch((err)=> {
            dispatch({type:  REG_FAIL, err});
            console.log(err.response.data); // shows console.log for this though.
        })

    }
}
```

**reducer**

```
import { SET_USER, REG_SUC, REG_FAIL, lOG_FAIL} from '../actions/';


const initialState = {
    authError: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    token: null,
    user: [],
    getToken: localStorage.getItem('JWT')
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            return ({
                ...state,
                user:action.user,
                token: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true
            });
        case lOG_FAIL:
            return({
                ...state,
                authError:action.err
            });
        case REG_SUC:
            return({
                ...state,
                user:action.user,
                isAuthenticated:true,
            });
        case REG_FAIL:
            return({
                ...state,
                authError:action.err.response.data
            });

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**signIn component**

```
class signIn extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            formData:{
                username:"",
                password: ""
            },
            loggedEmail:"",
            loginError: "",
            myToken:"", 
            userLoggedIn: false,
            emailBlank: true,
            passwordBlank: true,
            emailInvalid: false,
            passwordInValid: false,
            // token:localStorage.getItem('JWT')
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const { formData } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            formData: {
              ...formData,
              [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        });

    }


    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const {formData} = this.state;
        const {username,password} = formData;
        this.setState({
            username: this.state.username, 
            password: this.state.password

        });

        const creds = {
            username, password
        }
        this.props.logIn(creds);
        console.log(creds);


    }

    componentDidMount(){

    }

    render(){


        if( this.props.token){
            return(
                <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div style={ {padding: '20px 100px'}}>
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>      
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name2"
                    label="Username"
                    className=""
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    name="username"
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  
                <br></br>
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    className=""
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  

                <br></br>

                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Log In
                </Button>

            </form>

            </div>

        );
    }





}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    token: state.user.getToken
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      logIn: (user) => dispatch(logIn(user))

});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(signIn));
```

**SignUp Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {register} from  '../actions/';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class signUp extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            formData:{
                username:"",
                password: "",
                passwordConf:"",
                email:""
            },
            passErr: "",
            regSuccess: false
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const { formData } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            formData: {
              ...formData,
              [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        });

    }


    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const {formData} = this.state;
        const {username, email, password, passwordConf} = formData;
        this.setState({
            username: this.state.username, 
            password: this.state.password,
            passwordConf: this.state.passwordConf,
            email:this.state.email,


        });

        const creds = {
            username, email, password
        }
        if(password === passwordConf){
            this.props.register(creds);
        }

        else{
            this.setState({
                passErr: "Passwords Don't Match"
            })
        }


    }

    render(){
      const {token } = this.props
        if(token){
            return <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>
        }

        return (
            <div style={ {padding: '20px 100px'}}>

            {this.props.error && (
                    <div style={{color:'red'}}>
                        {this.props.error}
                    </div>            
            )}

            {this.state.passErr && (
                    <div style={{color:'red'}}>
                        {this.state.passErr}
                    </div>            
            )}


            <h1>Sign Up</h1>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>      
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Username"
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    name="username"
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />
            <br></br>
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Email"
                    className=""
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    name="email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  
                <br></br>
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    className=""
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  
             <br></br>
              <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Confirm Password"
                    name="passwordConf"
                    type="password"
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    className=""
                    value={this.state.passwordConf}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  

                <br></br>

                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Sign Up
                </Button>

            </form>

            </div>

        );
    }





}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    token: state.user.getToken,
    error: state.user.authError
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    register: (user) => dispatch(register(user))

});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(signUp));
```

**backend**

```
router.post('/loginUser', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('login', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (info != undefined) {
      console.log(info.message);
      res.send(info.message);
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
       models.User.findOne({
          where: {
            username: req.body.username,
          },
        }).then(user => {
          const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id  }, 'nodeauthsecret');
          res.status(200).send({
            auth: true,
            token: token,
            message: 'user found & logged in',
          });
        });
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code is fine, please post more information such as console debug and network requests. Or a link to the entire code because from what you posted a minimal example still functions.

Comment: i post a pic, not sure if its anything helpful

Comment: can you share the code? Because I've recreated your sign in component and mapped the login function and it works fine.

Comment: what part of the code should i share, i shared the back end as well.

Comment: All components, no back end code needed.

Comment: Can you show the network tab and the response for the login request, show the headers please

Comment: ok i shared the signup component(so u can see how that works), and the network tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187784/discussion-between-win-and-randal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the login request was posting a `200` okay response when it was failing. Therefore axios couldn't catch the error. Fixing the response status solved this issue on the backend.

```
res.status(401).send(info.message);
```