# express ignoring 403 error when using redux + react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

Redux, or express seems to be ignoring an error, when a user updates their password when they are given an reset password link token.

[image]

[image]

It should render this error

```
if (this.props.error) {
      return (
        <div>
          <AppBar title={title} />
          <div style={loading}>
            <h4>Problem resetting password. Please send another reset link.</h4>

          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

However, whatever condition it is, whether the password is empty or filled, it returns successful when it shouldn't.

their is a similar post like this

[React Redux is ignoring dispatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493393/react-redux-is-ignoring-dispatches)

and the solution had to be an issue with my backend, however for something like this it seems to be correct.

Could it be the backend or redux not dispatching properly ?

**backend**

```
router.put('/updatePassword', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (info != undefined) {
      console.log(info.message);
      res.status(403).send(info.message);
    } else {
      models.User.findOne({
        where: {
          username: req.body.username,
        },
      }).then(user => {
        if (user != null) {
          console.log('user found in db');
          bcrypt
            .hash(req.body.password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS)
            .then(hashedPassword => {
              user.update({
                password: hashedPassword,
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('password updated');
              res
                .status(200)
                .send({ auth: true, message: 'password updated' });
            });
        } else {
          console.log('no user exists in db to update');
          res.status(404).json('no user exists in db to update');
        }
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

**Front End**

```
class ResetPassword extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      update: false,
      isLoading: true,
      error: false,
    };
  }

async componentDidMount() {

  // this.props.Reset();
    await axios
      .get('/api/users/reset', {
        params: {
          resetPasswordToken: this.props.match.params.token,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.message === 'password reset link a-ok') {
          this.setState({
            username: response.data.username,
            update: false,
            isLoading: false,
            error: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        this.setState({
          update: false,
          isLoading: false,
          error: true,
        });
      });
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  updatePassword = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {username, password} = this.state;

    const creds = {
      username, password
    }

    if(password != null){
      this.props.updatePass(creds);
    }
    else{
      console.log('enter an email')
    }

    // axios
    //   .put('/api/users/updatePasswordViaEmail', {
    //     username: this.state.username,
    //     password: this.state.password,
    //   })
    //   .then(response => {
    //     console.log(response.data);
    //     if (response.data.message === 'password updated') {
    //       this.setState({
    //         updated: true,
    //         error: false,
    //       });
    //     } else {
    //       this.setState({
    //         updated: false,
    //         error: true,
    //       });
    //     }
    //   })
    //   .catch(error => {
    //     console.log(error.data);
    //   });
  };

  render() {
    const { password, error, isLoading, updated } = this.state;

    if (this.props.error) {
      return (
        <div>
          <AppBar title={title} />
          <div style={loading}>
            <h4>Problem resetting password. Please send another reset link.</h4>

          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={loading}>Loading User Data...</div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
         <h1> Update Password</h1>

         {this.props.updated && (
            <div>
              <p>
                Your password has been successfully reset, please try logging in
                again.
              </p>

            </div>
          )}

          <form className="password-form" onSubmit={this.updatePassword}>
            <TextField
              id="password"
              label="password"
              style={Styles.textF}
              onChange={this.handleChange('password')}
              value={password}
              type="password"
            />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <Button color="primary" variant="outlined" type="submit">
            Update Password
         </Button>
          </form>


        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // token: state.user.getToken, 
  // error: state.post.postError
  // showError: state.account.showError,
  // messageFromServer: state.account.messageFromServer
  updated: state.account.update,
  isLoading: state.account.isLoading,
  error: state.account.error


})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  Reset: () => dispatch(Reset()),
  updatePass: (creds) => dispatch(updatePass(creds))
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResetPassword));
```

**Redux actions**

```
export const updatePass = (creds)  => {
    return  (dispatch) =>{
        axios.put('/api/users/updatePasswordViaEmail', {
            username: creds.username,
            password: creds.password,
        }).then(response => {
            // console.log(creds.username);
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.message === 'password updated') {
                dispatch({type:UPDATEPASS, creds});     
            }

         }).catch(err => {

            dispatch({type:UPDATEPASS_FAIL, err});  


         });
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
case UPDATEPASS:
            return({
                ...state,
                update:true,
                error: false

            });
        case UPDATEPASS_FAIL:
            return({
                ...state, 
                update: false,
                error: true,
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `ResetPassword` component. You set the initial value of `password` to be an empty string. Because of that, the following will always be true:

```
if (password != null) {
    this.props.updatePass(creds);
}
```

To fix your issue, check that the `password` is not an empty string instead:

```
if (password !== '') {
    this.props.updatePass(creds);
}
```

Comment: let me try this out.

Comment: this works fine. but how would i make the error `please enter an email` into a redux dispatch action.

Comment: That's a different question. In short, you can add an `errorMessage` to the state returned by your reducer for action `UPDATEPASS_FAIL`: `{ ...state, update: false, error: true, errorMessage: 'Your message' }`. You can then use that message in your component.